# What will be the cause this DXA Error for MediaItem class?

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

Please help me out for this issue. Is this the cause of contentUrl?

> Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticAnnotationException: The field private java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.api.model.entity.MediaItem.url has a @SemanticProperty annotation with prefix 's', but the entity class has no @SemanticEntity annotation with this prefix.

This is the available in `MediaItem` class in Common API jar.

```
@SemanticProperty("s:contentUrl")
@JsonProperty("Url")
private String url;
```

Comment: Can you please provide the entire Entity class source code?

Comment: For clarity: class `MediaItem` is an abstract class and hence cannot be instantiated itself; only concrete subclasses can be instantiated. Which subclass are you using? How is it defined?  We really need more info to be able to answer this question.